# Segmentation fault generated by mkfifo() in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mkfifo

I've been trying to debug this for a few hours now and I'm still stuck...

I get a segmentation fault with a "mkfifo" call in this code (it is only a part of my entire code, since I figured the rest was not relevant here) :

```
#include "marketfunc.h"
#include "error.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define PIPE_PATH "./pipe.fifo"

struct myStruct
{
    int x;      
    int y;
    int z;  
};


struct myStruct *s;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    s = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));

    // 'int marketfunc_init(int x)' is defined in a perfectly working extern library
    if(marketfunc_init(1) == -1) error("failed to initialize marketfunc library", 5);

    printf("test1\n");

    // Segmentation fault
    if(mkfifo(PIPE_PATH, 0666) == -1) error("failed to create pipe", 1);

    printf("test2\n");

    //...

}
```

Which produces this output (executableFile beeing the name of my file):

```
test1
bin/executableFile: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The gdb backtrace produces this:

```
#0  strchrnul () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchr.S:32
#1  0x00007ffff7a5ed82 in __find_specmb (format=0xffffffffffffff60 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffff60>)
    at printf-parse.h:108
#2  _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7fffffffb5a0, format=0xffffffffffffff60 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffff60>, 
    ap=0x7fffffffdd58) at vfprintf.c:1332
#3  0x00007ffff7a63f31 in buffered_vfprintf (s=s@entry=0x7ffff7dd41c0 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>, 
    format=format@entry=0xffffffffffffff60 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffff60>, args=args@entry=0x7fffffffdd58)
    at vfprintf.c:2356
#4  0x00007ffff7a5eeae in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff7dd41c0 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>, 
    format=format@entry=0xffffffffffffff60 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffff60>, ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffdd58)
    at vfprintf.c:1313
#5  0x00007ffff7b0c595 in error_tail (status=status@entry=4199947, errnum=errnum@entry=1, 
    message=message@entry=0xffffffffffffff60 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffff60>, args=args@entry=0x7fffffffdd58)
    at error.c:201
#6  0x00007ffff7b0c6ed in __error (status=4199947, errnum=1, 
    message=0xffffffffffffff60 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffff60>) at error.c:251
#7  0x0000000000400b78 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf38) at src/executableFile.c:75
```

Though the "pipe.fifo" file is created...
Thanks in advance for your help !

EDIT:

error is simply defined as such in error.c and it's signature in error.h:

```
#include "error.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void error(char *msg, int ret)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(ret);
}
```

Comment: It looks like `error` is the culprit, but we don't know how it is defined

Comment: `REQUESTS_PIPE_PATH` or `PIPE_PATH`? Is `s` a pointer to a structure, or an actual structure instance? Things like these will distract from the actual problem you have, please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The purposes of MCVE are several: the problem can be easily replicated by commenters (or not); you don't assume "the rest of the code does not cause the bug" (since you don't *know* where the bug is); and quite often, preparing the MCVE will reveal to you what the problem is, as you do it.

Comment: I've edited the post to clarify a bit.
Thanks for your quick answers.

Comment: In  `s = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));`the struct variable `s` is not a pointer. Do you have warnings enabled?

Comment: And in any case you have at least one typo `struct myStruc s;`. Please don't tinker with this on-the-fly: post the MCVE requested.

Comment: It is a good idea to always include your own include files **after** the system include files. `error` might be defined in one of the system include files.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad thanks for the reminder :)
I just modified this in my code, but it didn't solve the problem :/

Comment: Try commenting the call to `marketfunc_init()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the stack trace, you will see that the call to `error()` shows up as:

```
0x00007ffff7b0c6ed in __error (status=4199947, errnum=1, message=0xffffffffffffff60 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffff60>) at error.c:251
```

This is **NOT** the `error()` function that you defined. But rather, it is the `error()` function defined in `error.h` with the following signature:

```
void error(int status, int errnum, const char *format, ...);
```

See [error.h](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/error.3.html).

As you can see, this function expects a `char* format` as the last argument, which is getting some junk off the stack `0xffffffffffffff60`, because you don't pass in the third argument at all. It would seem that the linker is resolving the call to `error()` to the wrong function.

As a quick fix, I would rename things as follows:

```
rename your file `error.h` to `error_my.h`

your definition of `error()` to, say, `error_my()`

replace the calls to `error()` with `error_my()`.
```

Your code would look like:

```
#include "marketfunc.h"
#include "error_my.h" // <=======================
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define PIPE_PATH "./pipe.fifo"

struct myStruct
{
    int x;      
    int y;
    int z;  
};


struct myStruct *s;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    s = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));

    // 'int marketfunc_init(int x)' is defined in a perfectly working extern library
    if(marketfunc_init(1) == -1) error_my("failed to initialize marketfunc library", 5); // <=======================

    printf("test1\n");

    // Segmentation fault
    if(mkfifo(PIPE_PATH, 0666) == -1) error_my("failed to create pipe", 1); // <=======================

    printf("test2\n");

    //...

}
```

Print out `errno` when `mkfifo()` fails to figure out why it is failing in the first place.

Comment: Thanks very much, that fixed the issue ! I was so focused on the mkfifo call that I didn't even think about checking this...